# CSS: apply table border to one table and not another

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I applied the below table border to all of the tables on my site

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td{
    border: 1px solid #999;
```

How do I do no border on some of the tables while keeping the border on the others?

Answer (score 1):

You can target elements with a specific class or id to style:

```
#tableOne {
    border: none;
}

.borderlessTable {
    border: none;
}
```

Alternatively you could do it the other way around and add the border to tables with a specific class/id.

Comment: I did what you requested <table id="tablenoborder"> in html & #tablenoborder {
    border: none;
} in css      while maintaining my original styles in the original post but my table still shows up with borders.  Didn't work

Comment: It's because you've applied the border to the header and cells, with CSS the most specific rule takes precedent. So in your case you would need to do: 

`.borderlessTable td, .borderlessTable th {
    border: none;
}`